# Read and Write root folder wihout root

Tags: android, file-io

I have seen an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fankewong.angrybirdsbackup2sd)(i don't mean to advertise) that can backup other app file that stores in the root folder. I am curious how it works **without root**.

I have tried several ways like

```
File file = new File(PATH);
```

and using adb pull and push

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb pull PATH");
```

But they are not successful.

**Question :** How they done the app? Is it because angrybirds provide some special permissions?

Comment: I tried using ICS device, but it is not success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `run-as` on some devices to execute commands as a particular package. Google have fixed this on Jelly Bean so it no longer works:

```
adb shell
run-as app.package.name \
cp /data/data/package.name/file.txt /sdcard/
exit
adb pull /sdcard/file.txt ~/
```

[Here](http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/access-android-app-data-without-root.html) is a good article explaining file access in Android without root permissions, including a one-liner for the above script.

It details how to use the new `backup` command:

```
backup -f ~/data.ab -noapk app.package.name
```

And how to extract the contents of the resulting .ab file:

```
dd if=data.ab bs=1 skip=24 | openssl zlib -d | tar -xvf -
```

You will most likely need the `android.permission.BACKUP` permission.

Answer (score 0):

For the your application have to a admin rights for that you have to bind device admin

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
```